# Как вывести последние сообщения, в которых пользователь принимал участие?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `text` text NOT NULL,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `read` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Есть таблица, как вывести последние сообщения, в которых пользователь принимал участие.

Вот дам самой таблицы:

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `from`, `to`, `text`, `date`, `read`) VALUES
(1, 56, 60, 'xfgvbxfgbfgb', '2014-10-10 10:11:33', '0'),
(2, 60, 56, ' rtdrtyhdtryjftujfyujyfju', '2014-10-10 11:12:14', '0'),
(3, 56, 62, 'srtgrtgdrtg', '2014-10-10 21:32:26', '0'),
(4, 67, 56, 'vdxfvdfvdf', '2014-10-10 22:04:38', '0');
```

Comment: таблица вида id|from|to|text|date|read

Comment: @ukroficer, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

@ukroficer, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как решить данную проблему.

Comment: @ukroficer, у вас 0% принятых ответов на ваши вопросы. Проявите уважение к отвечающим. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на какой-либо из ваших 34 вопросов, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).  
Если устраивающих ответов по вашему мнению нет (в этом лично у меня есть сомнения), возможно стоить приложить усилия к улучшению качества вопросов. В частности данный вопрос вызывает еще больше вопросов, которые задавать особо никто спешить не будет.  
[Полезная ссылка](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#code) о том как задавать правильные вопросы.

Comment: @ukroficer

> проблема в том что я не знаю как решить данную проблему.

Это, конечно, занятный каламбур, но дело так не пойдет.

> как вывести последние сообщение в которых пользователь принимал участие.

Тут выше справедливо заметили про принятые вопросы. Поэтому я просто опишу алгоритм, как БД должна искать такие вещи.

1. Найти все сообщения пользователя.
2. Отсортировать по дате.
3. Взять первые результаты.

Надеюсь, это не слишком сложно.

Comment: Нет, вы не поймете сложность, пока сами не попробуете решить эту задачу. Поймите, я могу быть и тот, кто шлет, и тот, кому шлют.

Comment: @ukroficer, я ее решил в течение трех секунд после того, как взглянул на схему. Собственно, решение целиком и так уже приведено выше, его просто надо перевести в SQL.

Comment: Если вы ее решили, покажите SQL запрос?

Comment: >Нет вы не поймете сложность пока сами не попробуете решить эту задачу. Поймите я могу быть как тот кто шлет и тому кто шле

эмм..ваша сложность в том, чтобы вместо условия 

    WHERE [from] = @userId

написать условие 

    WHERE [from] = @userId OR [to] = @userId 

?

Comment: Потому что одним OR не обойдешься, нам нужно одно сообщение, причем последнее в каждом диалоге независимо от того, было оно от меня или ко мне.

Comment: @ukroficer вы как-то очень уж бессвязно объясняете. Мы вам были бы искренне рады помочь, но нам правда сложно понять из ваших путанных слов, что же именно вы хотите, почему это не получается и чем вас не устраивают предлагаемые решения.Лично мне видится, что вы хотите получить энное количество сообщений, которые адресованных пользователю или же автором которых он был сам за какой-то период времени. Так вот у этой задачи есть очень простое решение - условие
    
    WHERE [from] = @userId OR [to] = @userId

плюс  сортировка по убыванию даты. Собственно, больше ничего не нужно выдумывать.

Comment: Автор вопроса отжигает :)

    WHERE [from] = @userId OR [to] = @userId ORDER BY [date] DESC

Comment: @kohana ORDER BY [Date] DESC, раз уж речь о последних сообщениях

Comment: Извините, но вы не знаете, о чем говорите, или не понимаете вопрос, напишите SQL запрос, я Вам сразу скажу, что не так.

Comment: Еще раз говорю, что OR проблему полостью не решает, так как сообщение должно быть последним, независимо были отправителем или получателем. Добавил дамп самой таблицы.

Comment: >извините но вы не знаете о чем говорите или не понимаете вопрос

@ukroficer ну так попытайтесь это грамотно и внятно объяснить, а не ходить вокруг да около. Здесь же не клуб веселых ребусов и загадок. Ладно бы вас кто-то один не понимал, так вас вообще никто понять не может. Может дело-то не в ответах, а в вопросе? (кроме ого, вы на каждый вариант ответа говорите, что он не подходит, но при этом не говорите почему)

>так как сообщение должно быть последним не зависимо были отправителем или получателем

как вы могли заметить, вам тут раза три уже писали про ORDER BY

Comment: Я не получил ни одного ответа SQL запроса, or не подходит, так как он не правильно работает. Есть вверху дамп таблицы. Прочитайте вопрос, что конкретно нужно получить. Я напомню: "Как вывести последние (одно) сообщения, в которых пользователь принимал участие."

Comment: SQl должен получить. 

id 2,3,4. id = 1 не должно выбираться, так как в диалоге 56 и 60 последнее сообщение с id = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, заканчиваем глум

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE `from` = :id OR `to` = :id
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Это простой вывод всех последних сообщений с пользователем.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE `from` = :id OR `to` = :id
GROUP BY `from`, `to`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Выбирает уникальные пары from/to, но в пары (56, 60) и (60, 56) будут считаться разными.

Ну и наконец мастодонт, который отвратителен, но будет работать еще вероятнее:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, `from` AS inspected_user,
        `to` AS interlocutor, `date`,
        `text`, `read`
    FROM messages AS m1
    WHERE `from` = :id
    UNION
    SELECT id, `to` AS inspected_user,
        `from` AS interlocutor, `date`,
        `text`, `read`
    FROM messages AS m2
    WHERE `to` = :id
  ) AS messages
  ORDER BY `date` DESC -- я тупой и не придумал, как избавиться от этого
) AS messages_outer
GROUP BY `interlocutor`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Отдельно отмечу, что одна эта таблица содержит в себе сразу пять зарезервированных слов - from, text, date, to, read.

P.S. А если с самого начала организовать диалоги отдельной сущностью, то можно сохранить мозг в сохранности.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c328b/7)

Comment: Не удивлюсь, если автору это не поможет :)